# Google Code Prettify Conflict with HTML

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, prettify, google-code-prettify

I am trying to use google-code-prettify to highlight the syntax of some code, but the browser is rendering the HTML I am including in the tags. I have followed the Getting Started instructions

e.g.

```
    <pre class="prettyprint">
      <head>
          <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
           <div id="divId">
        <h1 class="h1Class">Hello world</h1>
           </div>
      </body> 
    </pre>

    <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

Here, all I get is `Hello world`. I have tried adding `lang-html` after `class="prettyprint`, didn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: @mason fixed and edited, but still not working. and yes that is the code

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

`<` with `&lt;`

and

`>` with `&gt;`